# Php page restriction

Tags: php

I want to restrict some pages on my controlpanel. I know there is alot of information on the internet and most of those questions has already been asked. But i still can't figur out why it doesn't work for me.

So I have try'd to add the following to one of the pages on the controlpanel:

```html
<?php
    
    if (!session_id()) { 
      session_start();
    }

    if (!$_SESSION['u_id']){ 
      header("Location: fout.php?message=paginaontoegankelijk");
      die();
    }
    include_once 'header1.php';
    include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
```

So when someone tries to enter the page without being logged in it will refuse. It works fine and well. I want to make this page accessible for only someone with u_id == 'hans' so i tried to change the code to :

```html
<?php

    
    if (!session_id()) { 
      session_start();
    }

    // If u_id isnt same as 'hans' redirect to fout.php
    if (isset($_SESSION ['u_id']) != 'hans'){ 
      header("Location: fout.php?message=paginaontoegankelijk");
      die();
    }
    include_once 'header1.php';
    include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
```

Somehow this isn't working, when i do this i can still access it with other accounts.

```html
$_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['gebruiker_id'];
```

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean, not a string. So your `if` is currently asking if `true` or `false` is not equal to `hans` which is always true, so you get redirected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isset($_SESSION ['u_id'])` does not return a string. It returns a boolean (true or false).

You have to use :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['u_id']) && $_SESSION['u_id'] != 'hans')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to check if the variable exists and also to check its value:

```
if (isset($_SESSION ['u_id']) && $_SESSION['u_id'] != 'hans')
```

The [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) PHP's function:

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

and return a `boolean`:

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.